# Installing specific Package (New Version)

Tags: apt

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and my current version of Open Blas is 0.1alpha2.2-3.  There is a bug in this version that has been fixed by https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openblas/+bug/817212

How can I install this newer version which has resolved the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually download the v2.6 `.deb` from Ubuntu Raring (13.04) here : http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libopenblas-base (choose your architecture, amd64 is 64 bit and i386 is 32 bit), then [install it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line) on your system.

You could also add a PPA to get the updates, currently v2.8 (may broke your system : *No PPA can be confirmed 100% safe for use or not. PPAs are a use-at-your-own-risk solution, but most times they're generally safe but there could be other system issues on your end that can cause PPA'd software to break*) :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rdev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade libopenblas-base
```

-

Note: Here, with OpenBlas, depedencies are satisfied, so you will be able to do this. It is not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

this might help:

```
  apt-get --purge remove (package)     
  apt-get upgrade (package name)
```

Comment: Not in this case. Precise (12.04) has the bugged version in the packages sources. Source http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libopenblas-base